# Using data external to receive variable from bash script in terraform

Tags: terraform, sh

I want to fetch sshkey with digital ocean token with `get_sshkey.sh` script:

```
do_token=$1


curl -X GET -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${do_token//\"}" "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/account/keys?page=1" | jq -r --arg queryname "User's key" '.ssh_keys[] | select(.name == $queryname).public_key'
```

I have a declared variable of DO token `var.do-token`, I am trying to use `$1` bash concept to pass parameter to `get_sshkey.sh` and run it in terraform `data "external"` in following:

```
data "external" "fetchssh" {
  program = ["sh", "/input/get_sshkey.sh `echo "var.do-token" | terraform -chdir=/input console -var-file terraform.auto.tfvars`"]
```

}

but get the error: `Expected a comma to mark the beginning of the next item.`

Comment: Any updates on this? Have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

In order to include literal quotes in your shell command, you'll need to escape them so that Terraform can see that you don't intend to end the quoted string template:

```
data "external" "fetchssh" {
  program = ["sh", "/input/get_sshkey.sh `echo \"var.do-token\" | terraform -chdir=/input console -var-file terraform.auto.tfvars`"]
}
```

Using the `external` data source in Terraform to recursively run another `terraform` is a pretty irregular thing to do, but as long as there's such a variable defined in that configuration I suppose it could work.

Comment: This returns `Error: failed to execute "sh": sh: can't open '/input/get_sshkey.sh `echo "var.do-token" | terraform -chdir=/input console -var-file terraform.auto.tfvars`': No such file or directory`, however if I run '/input/get_sshkey.sh `"`echo "var.do-token" | terraform -chdir=/input console -var-file terraform.auto.tfvars`"` separately it returns appropriate token hash: sh: `"tokenhash": not found`